# using vue prop in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2

hello guys i google a lots and i found that props should use to pass parameter from laravel blade(location resource/view) to vue component(location resource/assets/) my version of vue is 2 here is my register blade

```
      @extends('layouts.auth')

       @section('content')
          <router-view name="register" :route="{{ route('my-route') }}">
           </router-view>


     @endsection
```

here is my app.js file(location resource/asset)

```
  require('./bootstrap');
  window.Vue = require('vue');
  import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

   window.Vue.use(VueRouter);

  import Register from './website/auth/register.vue';


   const routes = [
          {path: '/register', component: Register, name: 'register'},
        ]

         const router = new VueRouter({ routes })

      const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')
```

here is my register.vue

```
      <template>
          <a :href="route">back</a>
         </template>
          <script>
             export default{
                       prop: ['route'],
               mounted() {
          console.log(this.route);
            },
       }
          </script>
```

but it throw undefine why i m not getting value of route 
 help me i m new to vue

Answer (score 1):

```
<router-view name="register" :route="{{ route('my-route') }}">
```

The value of your `:route` attribute is `{{ route('my-route') }}` which doesn't work. `{{ ... }}` will be evaluated by the Blade templating language and will result in a string (I assume). I the route is `example` the HTML outputted by Blade will look like this:

```
<router-view name="register" :route="example">
```

This *seems* fine, but there's one big mistake which is the usage of [`v-bind:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) or in your case [the shorthand `:`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) in front of the attribute name.

[The Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) says the following on `v-bind`:

> **Dynamically** bind one or more attributes, or a component prop to **an expression**.

In your case the route is neither dynamic (it's generated by Blade on the server-side) nor an expression (`:route="'example'"` would be valid since `'example'` is an expression).

The solution is to simply remove `:`.

```
<router-view name="register" route="{{ route('my-route') }}">
```

---

**There's also a typo in your code:** It should be `props` not `prop`.